# Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed in

Tags: php, session

I am receiving the following error randomly when going through the session login code; Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed in...,

I am using WAMP with PHP5.5.12 on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit

```html
$session_name = 'seam_secure_session_id';
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
session_name($session_name);
session_start();

session_regenerate_id(true);// regenerated the session, delete the old one.

ob_start();
```

I receive no other session warnings or errors, and the login code is called at the start of my code before any HTML. I have checked php.ini and the session.save_path. Permissions are fine (Authenticated users, SYSTEM, admin, User all have full control) on the save path, the sessions files are being saved in the folder.

I am at a loss, any ideas?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you see the warning because "session_regenerate_id(true)" tries to delete the old session, but the session maybe isn't written at this point. PHP will write the session-file at the end of the script, at the mean time the session values are only in memory. This is also the reason why we use session_write_close or exit after a header redirect, so that the session is written already at this point.

Maybe you can check if the session is available before you try to delete it? e.g.: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/commit/45d6a7d51be2ea12a935a94511290cb9670706d9

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and resolved it by updating Read and Write permissions to the folder as described here at [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15259#issuecomment-348231652). Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I tell you what worked for me: I read the error that says: ** Warning: session_regenerate_id (): The destruction of the session object failed ... **
What did I do? I simply go to the folder that indicates the text and I delete all the keys stored there, and I solved the problem, it took me out of the session but now that I enter and leave again there is no more error

Answer (score -4):

Try adding '@' just before the line no 300 of the Session.php file

path of session.php file could be:
`C:\xampp1\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Session.php`

code before adding @ is :

```
public function regenerateID($deleteOldSession = false)
{
    if ($this->getIsActive()) {

        // add @ to inhibit possible warning due to race condition
        // https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/1812
        if (YII_DEBUG && !headers_sent()) {

            session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
        } else {

            @session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
        }
    }
}
```

code after adding @ is:

```
public function regenerateID($deleteOldSession = false)
{
    if ($this->getIsActive()) {

        // add @ to inhibit possible warning due to race condition
        // https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/1812
        if (YII_DEBUG && !headers_sent()) {
            @session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
        } else {
            @session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

try to add @ before session_regenerate_id() like

```
@session_regenerate_id(true);
```

I was also facing the same issue but when i added @ before session_regenerate_id(true) it disappears and system works accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It hides warning only. But your actual issue is not solved.

Comment: Muting function output with @ to hide an error looks pretty much as putting on a raincoat to hide the fact that a man is bleeding